# Dispatch an action in a non-react-native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, action, dispatch

I'm trying to dispatch an action in a standalone JS function for my React-Native application.

I tried to do this, I can access to the state of the store, but when I'm dispatching an action, I don't have any error and nothing happen. Do you have an idea ?

```
// store.js
import { createStore } from 'redux'
export default createStore(reducers)


// myStandaloneFunction.js
import store from './store'
import myAction from './myAction'

console.log(store.getState())
store.dispatch(myAction) //here, nothing happen
console.log(store.getState()) //my props didn't change
```

Comment: try store.dispatch(myAction()) (you forgot the parenthesis () )

Comment: Already tried this. I forgot them in my example !